# Choose paypal gateway for my scenario

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

In our case we need the users to pre approve their payments during registration or before doing any business transaction..

once the authorize we need to deduct $X from their account on a monthly basis.. X will vary based on the earnings they have had in the month..
Also for some users we need to payout $Y on a monthly bases.. Y will vary based on their earnings that month...

is adaptive payment the right mode of payments for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that would probably be the best way to go, specifically the [Preapproval](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Preapproval_API_Operation/) and [Pay](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) APIs.

Alternatively, you could use the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) with [Billing Agreements and Reference Transactions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-refTrans-SetEC-DoRefTrans-curl-etc/).

I prefer Express Checkout because the experience is just better all around in my opinion.

Comment: If user has pre approved payment once than can I deduct amount monthly basis? (i mean without redirect on paypal)

Comment: Yes, you would use the Pay API with the Preapproval key that you got from the initial Preapproval API request.